# Selenium "return" javascript value not printing

Tags: java, javascript, selenium

I'm using Selenium with Java for some tests.
The code I have to print the pages html from javascript works great as an alert:

```
js.executeScript("alert($('html').html());");
```

However when I use **return**, nothing prints in the Eclipse console:

```
js.executeScript("return $('html').html();");
```

**What am I doing wrong, and how can i print (using System.out.print) the html result from returning in Javascript?** Thanks, and no I do not want to use source.

Comment: What happens if you assign a value to the `js.executeScript` invocation and print the value? (ie, `System.out.println(js.executeScript(..))`)

Comment: Glad to hear! The issue may be that the contents are indeed being returned but were not handled appropriately (ie, not printing via the `System.out.println` invocation).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `driver.getPageSource()` to get the result you want, I believe.

```
System.out.println(driver.getPageSource());
```

Comment: I know i said I don't want to use source in question, but this actually works for the parts of the page I was trying to retrieve, thanks.